# Bind rows with different data types

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some dataframes with more than 3000 columns in each, and I want to bind them together.

When I use

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(dataframe1, dataframe2, dataframe3, dataframe4)
```

I get a lot of warnings:

```
In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
...
```

I guess it's because a column has data of type factor in one dataframe and data of type character in another dataframe. But how can I solve this problem?

I know I can use

```
sapply(dataframe1, class)
```

to get the classes of a dataframe, but as there are many columns, it is impossible to go through them all in all 4 dataframes.

This seems to be a problem about the data, but what does it mean that something has type factor? Is it a number?

Comment: How are you importing your data frames into R? If using something like `read.csv()`, R will automatically convert any string variables into factors, with levels being set according to the order of unique strings. Guessing that the order of unique strings differs by data frame. You could use `read.csv(..., stringsAsFactors = F)` and convert to factor _after_ `bind_rows`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps start with `?factor` about what factors are.

To avoid the warnings, you either use `supressWarnings`, or you will need to convert to character first. For example (untested):

```
library(tidyverse)
l <- list(dataframe1, dataframe2, dataframe3, dataframe4)
map_dfr(l, ~mutate(., across(where(is.factor), as.character))
```

Comment: Where does `mutate_if()` come from? Not canonical `tidyverse`